# Regex email text with prefix and suffix

Tags: php, regex, email, prefix

I have two cases of html/text:

1. `My email is username@domen.com`
2. `My email is <a
   href="mailto:username@domen.com">username@domen.com</a>`

Also, I have function which is searching for email-links like and replace them with `<a href="email@address">email@address</a>` pattern, and it works. BUT, what if text already contains email-links. I don't want matching them too.

```
function make_email_links($text)
{
  return  preg_replace(
     array('/(([_A-Za-z0-9-]+)(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@([A-Za-z0-9-]+)
       (\\.[A-Za-z0-9-]+)*)/iex'
       ),
     array( 
       "stripslashes((strlen('\\2')>0?'<a href=\"mailto:\\0\">\\0</a>':'\\0'))" 
       ),
       $text
   );
}
```

I tried with

```
'/((^<a) .......... )/iex'
```

but it was unsuccessful. How to match only email-links like text but not real email-links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this:

```
$formattedTest = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])([a-z0-9&\-_\.]+?)@([\w\-]+\.([\w\-\.]+\.)*[\w]+)#i", "\\1<a href=\"mailto:\\2@\\3\">\\2@\\3</a>", $text);
```

I used the old one (this won't work!):

```
$formattedTest = preg_replace('/([\w\.!#\$%\-+.]+@[A-Za-z0-9\-]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9\-]+)+)/', '<a href="mailto:\\1">\\1</a>', $text);
```

But as you said it would have duplicated my email even if it's already inside an  tag.

Comment: in the first regex is just the delimiter character before and after the expresion. after the last # the modifiers appear (in this case 'i' comes from incase sensitive).

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
if (strstr($text, "<a href") !==false)
   return $text
```

before you do the preg_replace? (Or even a more save regex). Don't waste your time trying to get everything into "one" big pattern. Keep in mind: SourceCode is more often read, than written.